# Forest have label for nodes that is separate from content

Tags: forest

I am trying to get a hierarchical tree built using the forest package where each node is labelled with the parent nodes label + the node index, e.g,:
[image]

I've tried a lot of different things, including various node walks.
There are two issues:
1) labels appear directly above nodes (e.g., right on the edge line)
2) I can't get this recursive labelling working at all - the best I can do is make each nodes label "parentIndex.nodeIndex"

Comment: You expect us to retype your tree from the image just in order to create a style which labels the nodes? Only the last bit is interesting. The rest you've already done, so it's old hat.

Answer (score 4):

Since you not provide code for your tree, I use some my tree:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every label/.style={xshift=-4ex, text width=6ex, align=right, 
                             inner sep=1pt, font=\footnotesize, text=red}}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={              % style of tree nodes
      font=\footnotesize,
      draw, semithick, rounded corners,
            align = center,
        inner sep = 2mm,
                            % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
             edge = {draw, semithick, -stealth},
    parent anchor = east,
     child anchor = west,
             grow = south,
    forked edge,            % for forked edge
            l sep = 12mm,   % level distance
         fork sep = 6mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
                }
    [Multimedia\\ RSS,label=1
      [Multimedia\\ Content,label=1.1]
      [Multimedia\\ Content,label=1.2.3.4]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I actually wanted something where the numbers would be recursively appended, e.g., I wouldn't have to number them - I did figure something out but it's quite messy, I'll post it as an answer

Comment: @ZackNewsham And we actually wanted something like some code and not just a do-this-whole-thing-for-me picture.

Answer (score 4):

> I think I ought not answer do-it-for-mes like this one, especially
>   ones asked by those clearly capable of posting code. I'm going to
>   regardless because I like trees.
>
> I provide answers to do-it-for-mes on a strictly as-is basis. I answer
>   these questions not just because I want to but only, solely and purely
>   for that reason. Expect me to be less than sympathetic to requests for
>   explanations or adjustments. I spent the time setting the problem up.
>   If you'd wanted me to explain, you'd have helped me to help you.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    align=center,
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    l sep'+=15pt,
  },
  my label/.style={
    label={[anchor=south east]above:#1},
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for descendants={
      temptoksa/.option=n,
      for nodewalk={
        while={>On>{level}{1}}{u,+temptoksa=.,+temptoksa/.option=n}
      }{},
      my label/.register=temptoksa,
    },
  }
  [Things it is time to speak of \dots
    [Shoes
      [An invention designed to\\protect the wealthy and\\trample the poor.]
    ]
    [Ships
      [Occasionally to be\\found in bottles.]
    ]
    [Sealing was
      [Not to be confused\\with ceiling wax.]
    ]
    [Cabbages
      [{A traditional medicine for\\poverty, everywhere believed\\efficacious by the rich\\and known ineffective\\by the poor.}]
    ]
    [Kings
      [Hereditary obsolescence.]
    ]
    [Why the sea is boiling hot
      [\emph{Non sequitur}.]
    ]
    [Whether pigs have wings
      [Falsehood.
        [\emph{A posteriori.}]
        [Contingent.]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: auto-numbering]